# Use reinterpret_cast<char *> () with input of an array

Tags: c++, casting, pass-by-reference, reinterpret-cast

I am following a tutorial and I am using the following code to read a binary file into an array:

```
int binRead(int outputArray[], const string& fileName, const unsigned int length)
{
   ifstream inputData; 
   inputData.open(fileName);
   if (inputData){
       inputData.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(outputArray), sizeof(int) * length); 
       inputData.close();  
       return 0; 
   }else
       return -1; 
}
```

My question is firstly why we could cast an array of integers into characters? What is the underlying logic here?

Secondly, I wonder shouldn't we use a reference as input here? What I understand is that the `outputArrary` will only be a copy inside this function's scope

Comment: First thing to understand is that `outputArray` is not an array, it's a pointer. If your tutorial doesn't make that clear then it's time to find another tutorial. When used as a function parameter `T x[]` or even `T x[N]` makes `x` a pointer (exactly like `T* x`). It's impossible to have a function parameter be an array in C or C++.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to do more research on this.

Comment: "*why we could cast an array of integers into characters?*" - because the standard allows casting any object pointer to `char*` to access the raw bytes of the object being pointed at.

Answer (score 0):

you are reading from a file and what you read that is a `char`. IMO `int outputArray[]` should be a `char* outputArray` you should avoid casting.

I believe you must be passing a buffer as the first parameter and storing the file data in that buffer. as @john mentioned, it is not an array you are passing in this function.